# How to return the range of cells selected by user through Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range functions

Tags: excel, excel-2010

Is there any pre-defined function that returns the range of cells that have been selected by the user?
I need to store the same in Range object. How am I supposed to access it?

Comment: Use the Selection property of the Application object.  Note you should probably check to make sure the selected object is a range and not something else such as a Shape.

Comment: Alright! Thank you!